# Post Replication script in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-replication, transactional-replication

I have setup SQL Server 2008 Transactional Replication between 2 databases. Once the replication session is complete, I want to execute a T-SQL script. Is there a configuration to setup Post Replication script or a mechanism to identify replication is complete and I can hook any script after replication is complete? In case we don't have this configuartion, can we use triggers to identify whether a table has been updated completely during replication and hence use trigger to invoke Post Replication script?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check the  @post_snapshot_script parameter of sp_addpublication, or the Properties page of the publication, under Snapshot, you'll find a section for "Run Additional Scripts" with an option for pre- and post scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  I would suggest to look at data from system tables to verify details of published tables

Which objects in the database are published?

Publish DB

- SELECT * FROM sysarticles
- SELECT * FROM syspublications

Distribution DB

- Use Distribution
- GO
- SELECT * FROM distribution..mspublications

SubscriberDB

- USE SubscriptionDB
- SELECT * FROM MSsubscriptions
- SELECT * FROM MSsubscriber_info

Hope it Helps.