# SQL Server Transactional Replication - Execute Pre and Post Script

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, transactional-replication

I am using SQL Server 2008 and have transactional replication setup. I need to be able to execute a pre replication script on the publisher and then a post replication script on the subscriber. Is this possible with transactional replication?

I have found [this other article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724272/post-replication-script-in-sql-server-2008) on here, but the post script here only gets executed when the snapsnot is delivered to the subscriber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if you are running the Distribution Agent on a schedule.  Edit the Distribution Agent SQL Agent job.  Add a step prior to the Run Agent job step to execute a SQL script on the Publisher.  Then add a step after the Run Agent job step which executes [sp_addscriptexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174360.aspx) to post a SQL script to the Subscriber.

I have a post describing sp_addscriptexec in [Executing scripts with sp_addscriptexec](http://www.sqlrepl.com/sql-server/executing-scripts-with-sp_addscriptexec/).  I recommend trying this in your test environment prior to deploying to production.